# "must + [verb]" past simple

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, defective-verbs

Is there a way to use must in past simple?

Present simple: You must run.
Past perfect: You must have ran.

Past simple doesn't work: You must ran.
Not even with another word to indicate past (since must is ambiguous): I thought you must ran. (wrong)

Comment: Note that *You must have *ran* is ungrammatical. You do not use the past tense after *to have*.

Answer (score 1):

had to

I must go. (present)

I had to go. (past)

Answer (score 1):

Of the nine standard modal verbs in English, only eight of these are inflected for tense as four pairs:

| Present Tense | Past Tense |
| --- | --- |
| will | would |
| shall | should |
| can | could |
| may | might |

And these naturally pair like this:

| Present Tense | Past Tense |
| --- | --- |
| Today, I think I will go. | Yesterday, I thought I would go. |
| I think I can get to it today. | I thought I could get to it yesterday. |
| It looks like it may rain today. | It looked like it might rain that night. |

But the ninth modal, *must*, has no inflectional pair to use with either possible tense. It works best for a nonpast situation only:

| Present Tense | Past Tense |
| --- | --- |
| Today I have decided that I must go shopping. | Yesterday I had decided that I must go shopping. |
| She must finish her project today. | — |

And you cannot use *must have* either, because that is an epistemic use making a prediction of how the world is not a deontic use stating how the world needs to be but is not:

| Present Tense | Past Tense |
| --- | --- |
| Surely she has gone home already. | Surely she had gone home already. |
| I think she must have gone home already. | I thought she must have gone home already. |
| I think she will have gone home already. | I thought she would have gone home already. |

Therefore you must replace *must* with its periphrastic equivalent that employs a tensed auxiliary to carry the tense. Either *to have to* or *to be to* works fine for this:

| Present Tense | Past Tense |
| --- | --- |
| She has to finish this today. | She had to finish that yesterday. |
| She is to finish this today. | She was to finish that yesterday. |
| I think she has to have gone home already. | I thought she had to have gone home already. |
| I think she will have to finish tomorrow. | I thought she would have to finish tomorrow. |

When replacing *must* with one of those two periphrastic equivalents, the *to be to*  version is more likely to be used epistemically for a prediction, while *to have to* is more apt to be used deontically for an obligation.

But this is not guaranteed. For example, these are all predictions not obligations:

- This must be John at the door now.
- This has to be John at the door now.
- That had to be John at the door back then.
- That must have been John at the door back then.
- That had to have been John at the door back then.